# String replace with variable in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to replace some part of a string in batch with another string. But I don't know what this string will be.

So I would like to use a variable for this:

```
for /r %%i in (\file\tmp\*) do (
    call :createJob %%i 
)
goto :eof

:createJob
    SETLOCAL
    set filename=%1
    for /F "delims=" %%i in (%filename%) do (
        set "line=%%i"
    )
    call :addId "%line%"
    ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:addId
    @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set string=%~1
    set /A "i=0"
    echo %string%
    for %%a in (%string%) do (
        if !i! EQU 1 (
            set id=;%%a;
            call set result=%string:!id!=;HELLO;%
        )
        echo %%a
        set /A "i+=1"
    )
    echo %result%
    ENDLOCAL
goto :eof   

:eof
```

I'm reading basic CSV files. In the function `addId`, the line `"call set result=%string:!id!=;HELLO;%"` doesn't work. The string is still the same. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you setting the FOR variable to the id variable?  There is no need to do that.  You should be able to do this: `set result=!string:;%%a;=;HELLO;!`

Comment: Well, it was because it didn't work so i tried few things !

Comment: It does work. Try it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
call set result=%%string:!id!=;HELLO;%%
```

Alternatively, test this:

```
set result=!string:;%%a;=;HELLO;!
```

Comment: Yeah, i just need to wait 4 more minutes before accepting the answer ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the problem that it seems to be impossible to directly use the command line arguments (like %1) in a batch script.
I had to use an intermediate variable like this:

```
set oldstring=%1
set newstring=%oldstring:oldpart=newpart%
```

Comment: What you say is correct (you can't use `%1` etc inside string replacement syntax) but I think the OP is not asking that question.  They want to know how to replace a string where the string to be replaced and the string to replace it with are themselves string variables - not string literals.